# SyntaxError: Unexpected token var in my js code

Tags: javascript, variables, inheritance

1. I am trying to finish a small js task, wrote the code but I am
   getting a SyntaxError: Unexpected token var . Can you guys tell me what error is in it.?
2. Modify the StudentReport class so that no grades will be printed to
   the console in the for-in loop.
3. However, getGPA should still function properly in the last line.

---

```
function StudentReport() {
    var grade1 = 4;
    var grade2 = 2;
    var grade3 = 1;
    var getGPA = function() {
        return (var grade1 + var grade2 + var grade3) / 3;
    };
}

var myStudentReport = new StudentReport();

for(var x in myStudentReport) {
    if(typeof myStudentReport[x] !== "function") {
        console.log("Muahaha! " + myStudentReport[x]);
    }
}

console.log("Your overall GPA is " + myStudentReport.getGPA());
```

Comment: `return (var grade1 + var grade2 + var grade3)` <- that's invalid !

Comment: Thats gruesome!! What'd you think?

Comment: If you look at the line where the error occurs, you should see it yourself. The error message is quite fitting.

Comment: Most of your tags don't apply.

Comment: i've removed some of them now

Answer (score 2):

You do not use `var` when you use a variable, only when you are defining it for the first time.

```
 return (var grade1 + var grade2 + var grade3) / 3;
         ^^^          ^^^          ^^^
```

but your code has more issues since you are checking for functions, but you did not code it to have any.

```
for(var x in myStudentReport) { <-- why are you looking through the function?
```

You want to be doing something like this

```
function StudentReport() {
    var grade1 = 4;
    var grade2 = 2;
    var grade3 = 1;
    this.getGPA = function() {
        return (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
    };
}

var myStudentReport = new StudentReport();
console.log(myStudentReport.getGPA());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here this doesn't make any sense, get rid of the `var`s there.

```
return (var grade1 + var grade2 + var grade3) / 3;
```